# XIB files in Cocoapod

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I just wrote a cocoapod and published it. Locally, it works just fine with the example.

However, when I try to install it through 'pod install' and use it, it has problems loading the XIB files.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:
```

I am currently loading the XIB file like this:

```
NSString* const frameworkBundleID  = @"org.cocoapods.MyPod";
NSBundle *podBundle =[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:frameworkBundleID];
```

earlier I also tried (the below) which worked locally as well.

```
NSBundle *podBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
```

What could I be doing wrong that makes it work locally but not after publishing?

Just for info, here's how the spec looks:

```
s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.{h,m}'

s.resource_bundles = {
'NetLogger' => ['Pod/Assets/*.xcassets', 'Pod/Classes/*.xib']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem a while ago. I fixed it by using a specific class as a reference instead of `self`:

```
NSBundle *podBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[ClassIncludedInPod class]];
```

For example to load `MyViewController` I would use:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [Bundle bundleForClass:[MyViewController class]];
MyViewController *myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" 
                                                            bundle:bundle];
```

Here in Swift:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: MyViewController.self)
let myVC = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: bundle)
```